# How to group by counted rows in Postgres?

Tags: postgresql

If I have a table:

```
 id | status 
----+--------
  2 |    200 
  1 |      0        
  4 |    100   
  3 |    200 
  5 |    200
```

I want to count the number of occurrences of each status.  I have tried to use the COUNT/OVER function

```
SELECT status, COUNT(*) OVER () AS all, COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION by status) as count FROM my_table;
```

The results are what is expected per the postgres docs on windows "However, window functions do not cause rows to become grouped into a single output row like non-window aggregate calls would. Instead, the rows retain their separate identities"

```
 status |   all | count 
--------+-------+-------
      0 |     5 |     1
    100 |     5 |     1
    200 |     5 |     3
    200 |     5 |     3
    200 |     5 |     3
```

How instead can get an output that combines the rows, so that I only get 1 row per unique status if the partition is required?

```
 status |   all | count 
--------+-------+-------
      0 |     5 |     1
    100 |     5 |     1
    200 |     5 |     3
```

Comment: Group again, and pick the first row using row_number().

Comment: @wildplasser I'm fairly new to Postgres, can you give an example usage?

Comment: Since you appear to be extending the question, I won't anser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No window function necessary in the first stage of the query, i.e. getting the counts per status. Window functions work on the result of the non-windowing part of the query, thus you can have a window function referring the aggregate & non-aggregate columns in a query. To get `all_counts`, it is sufficient to `SUM` the `status_count` over all the rows.

```
SELECT 
  status
, COUNT(*) status_count
, SUM(COUNT(*)) OVER () all_count
FROM my_table
GROUP BY status
```

Comment: Doh, my apologies, I should have specified the window function is required.  I picked a trivial case for the partition, but lets say its something else like PARTITION BY status > 100.

Comment: I added a second partition to hopefully make the partition requirement more explicit

Comment: <s> I still can't get a partition to work, like my example above PARTITION BY status > 100. OVER () works, but OVER ( PARTITION BY status > 100) does not </s>

Comment: ignore my comment, its not valid a valid case anways